# This regex works in regex website test, but not in Gawk

Tags: bash, awk

Using `GNU Awk 5.0.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)`, I want to check for a pattern using `match`.

My sample text is the following (with a space at the beginning of the line):

```
 7 Plasmas Mobiles (30%)
```

Using the following regex, I am able to match the string:

```
 [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \([0-9]{1,}%\)
```

As proved with this live example: regexr.com/6n3fh

However, awk's `match` returns 0:

```
awk '{print match($0, " [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \([0-9]{1,}%\)")}' reports/test
```

> awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain` ('
>
> awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain` )'
>
> 0

Why is that and how can I get the expected behavior, which is getting "1" as a return of `match` ?

Comment: Change to `match($0, / [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \([0-9]{1,}%\)/)` A quoted regex is a [Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps) in `awk`. See escaping requirement as a result of dynamic regex being scanned twice.

Comment: For example to use a dynamic regex, you would need  `match($0, " [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \\([0-9]{1,}%\\)")` (note the double `'\\'`)

Comment: Please be aware that there exist different so-called *flavors* of regular expressions, site you linked apparently uses either JavaScript or PCRE (i.e. as found in `perl`), for comparison see https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816

Comment: A regexp tested on an online site proves that that regexp works on that online site, nothing more. It does not mean it'll work in any specific command-line tool since every tool supports different regexp variants (e.g. BRE, ERE, and/or PCRE), with different delimiters (e.g. `"` or `/`), different options (e.g. backreferences and/or character class abbreviations), and different flags (e.g. `-r`, `-E`, or `-P`), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk` a regex is formed as `/the-regex/`, see [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html). `awk` does offer [Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps) where the regex is quoted as you have it.

`awk` treats the two styles of regex differently. Specifically the double-quoted string is scanned twice by `awk`. This necessitates escaping with a double backslash, e.g. `\\`.

In your case you can either use:

```bash
match($0, / [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \([0-9]{1,}%\)/)
```

or

```bash
match($0, " [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \\([0-9]{1,}%\\)")
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo " 7 Plasmas Mobiles (30%)" | awk '{print match($0, / [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \([0-9]{1,}%\)/)}'
1
```

and

```
$ echo " 7 Plasmas Mobiles (30%)" | awk '{print match($0, " [0-9]{1,} .{1,} \\([0-9]{1,}%\\)")}'
1
```